# how to read the time on a windows mobile device using c#

Tags: c#, time, windows-mobile, mobile-devices

What are the API provided in the Compact Framework to read the time (NOT in UTC!!)
on a windows mobile based device?

I was able to get the device time in UTC with this code:

```
DateTime dt = DateLib.Now;            
SystemTime sysTime = new SystemTime();
Windows.SystemTime.GetSystemTime(out sysTime);
Windows.SystemTime.ConvertTimeStructure(ref sysTime, out dt);
Windows.SystemTime.SetSystemTime(dt);
```

But I want the time as per the device's time zone.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you simply using the built-in, supported `DateTime.Now` property?

**EDIT**

The Compact Framework [caches timezone information on load](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555035), so any call to change the time zone after an app has loaded will not be reflected in a call to DateTime.Now.

Right now I assume you're P/Invoking `GetSystemTime`, instead you should be P/Invoking `GetLocalTime`.

Comment: So, what is happening is this: Suppose the device is on Pacific Standard Time (PST) and I launch my app and login. I get the correct time. Now I logout and change the Time Zone to say Central Standard Time. I login and hope that the time (DateTime.Now) would give the time as per the time in the clock & alarm application on the device (which is CST) but the time I get is still in PST. So, I decided to update the time on device before loging into my app. So, I'd first read the device time and then set it. But I do not know the right API.

Comment: DateLib.Now is just a wrapper around DateTime.Now and it chops the seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  DateTime.UtcNow to get the UTC Time. Get the current utc offset TimeZone

GetUtcOffset in order to get a TimeSpan.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.getutcoffset.aspx

Then you can get LocalTime = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeZone.GetUtcOffset